# Python Hadoop mrjob: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, mrjob

I'm using package `mrjob` on `Python3.7` recently. I started hadoop and created an `wordaccount.py` file, which can calculate the frequency of each word in an `.txt` file. When I tried to run the file through `python3 wordaccount.py -r hadoop data/hamlet.txt>1.txt`, here comes some problems:

```
xjj@master:/usr/local/hadoop/pyhadoop$ python3 wordaccount.py -r hadoop data/hamlet.txt>1.txt
No configs found; falling back on auto-configuration
No configs specified for hadoop runner
Looking for hadoop binary in /usr/local/hadoop/bin...
Found hadoop binary: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop
Using Hadoop version 2.7.1
Looking for Hadoop streaming jar in /usr/local/hadoop...
Found Hadoop streaming jar: /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.1.jar
Creating temp directory /tmp/wordaccount.xjj.20220522.085604.327723
uploading working dir files to hdfs:///user/xjj/tmp/mrjob/wordaccount.xjj.20220522.085604.327723/files/wd...
STDERR: 22/05/22 16:56:07 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
STDERR: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/xjj/tmp/mrjob/wordaccount.xjj.20220522.085604.327723/files/wd/mrjob.zip._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1550)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3110)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3034)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:723)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
STDERR:     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
STDERR:     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2043)
STDERR: 
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1476)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1407)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
STDERR:     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
STDERR:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
STDERR:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
STDERR:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
STDERR:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
STDERR:     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1430)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1226)
STDERR:     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:449)
STDERR: put: File /user/xjj/tmp/mrjob/wordaccount.xjj.20220522.085604.327723/files/wd/mrjob.zip._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wordaccount.py", line 19, in <module>
    WordCount.run()
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 616, in run
    cls().execute()
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 687, in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 636, in run_job
    runner.run()
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 503, in run
    self._run()
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 328, in _run
    self._upload_local_files()
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 1156, in _upload_local_files
    self._copy_files_to_wd_mirror()
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 1257, in _copy_files_to_wd_mirror
    self._copy_file_to_wd_mirror(path, name)
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 1238, in _copy_file_to_wd_mirror
    self.fs.put(path, dest)
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/fs/composite.py", line 151, in put
    return self._handle('put', path, src, path)
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/fs/composite.py", line 110, in _handle
    return getattr(fs, name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/fs/hadoop.py", line 321, in put
    self.invoke_hadoop(['fs', '-put', src, path])
  File "/home/xjj/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mrjob/fs/hadoop.py", line 183, in invoke_hadoop
    raise CalledProcessError(proc.returncode, args)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop', 'fs', '-put', '/tmp/wordaccount.xjj.20220522.085604.327723/mrjob.zip', 'hdfs:///user/xjj/tmp/mrjob/wordaccount.xjj.20220522.085604.327723/files/wd/mrjob.zip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

The content in `wordaccount.py` is as following. The function of it is calculating the frequency of every word occurred.

```
import os
import sys
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep
from mrjob.protocol import RawValueProtocol,JSONProtocol,ReprProtocol
import traceback
class WordCount(MRJob):
    def mapper(self, _, line):
        linearry = line.split()
        for word in linearry:
            yield word, 1
    def reducer(self, key, value):
        yield key,sum(value)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    WordCount.run()
```

I'm sure I have started hadoop through `sbin/start-all.sh`, and `wordaccount.py` and `hamlet.txt` actually exists. According to the Trackback, I have found the `hadoop.py`. So what changes should I make? Thanks.

Comment: _There are 0 datanode(s) running_ clearly indicates that either you dont have hadoop config in your pyhton path, or hadoop is not running altogether. _No configs specified for hadoop runner_ probably means its the former.

Comment: Hadoop 2.7.1 is rather old, by the way. You may want to upgrade, but this is unrelated to the error you're getting